# .NET 6 Swagger guid generates "https://localhost:5001/api/sth/%7Bid%7D"

Tags: c#, swagger, guid, .net-6.0

I have an issue with Swagger.

> When I try to pass a query as a parameter it malforms the URL-> `https://localhost:5001/api/sport/%7Bid%7D`

The expected result is this one:
`https://localhost:5001/api/sport/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001`
Which when called reached my endpoint.

I have this route parameter and my object look like this:

```
    [HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(SportEventResource),(int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = "Gets a new Sport event",
        Description = "Gets a new Sport event with its associative Markets and Selections",
        OperationId = "sportEvent.get",
        Tags = new[] { "SportEventEndpoints" })]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SportEventResource>> Get([FromRoute]GetSportEvent query)
    {...
    // The parameter looks like this...
    public class GetSportEvent : IQuery<Sport>
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
   // The rest is basically the auto generated values.
   // Rest of Setup => Program.cs
   builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
   {
      opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
      opt.EnableAnnotations();
   });

   
   if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
   {
      app.UseSwagger();
      app.UseSwaggerUI();
   }
```

> Here is how my Swagger is generated:
> Whenever I press execute I get a not found error and my endpoint is never called.
> Looking at the network tab i can see the malformed url: `https://localhost:5001/api/sport/%7Bid%7D`

[image]

Comment: Why is your method parameter a `GetSportEvent` rather than just the `Guid` itself?

Comment: Honestly just experimenting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by mismatched letter case - the parameter in the URI template `/api/sport/{id}` is named `id` (lowercase) but the method parameter is named `Id` (uppercase "I").

Try either changing `public Guid Id` to `public Guid id`

OR

changing `[HttpGet("{id:guid}")]` to `[HttpGet("{Id:guid}")]`.

Comment: Hello Helen, 
This works, thank you. 
It is kind of ugly. I would prefer just to use the Guid I guess.

Comment: I personally prefer @gunr2171's solution (i.e. replace the model with just Guid itself).

Answer (score 2):

`%7Bid%7D` url decodes to `{id}`, which makes ""sense"", you're asking for an object which has an Id property. That's a json-ish way of doing it.

Easy way to fix this is to remove your class and just bind the Guid directly.

```
[HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<SportEventResource>> Get([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
```

The parameter needs to be called `id` because that's what you have in the template (`"{id:guid}"`).

Comment: What you are saying here is not true. When I call directly from my browser this endpoint: `https://localhost:5001/api/sport/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001`. It works. Only swagger causes the issue.

Comment: Truthfully though what you say here is a workaround, which swagger likes...